# How to show this function is one to one (without using the complex mean value theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis

LEt $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an holomorphic while $\mathbb{D}$ is convex set and let  $Ref'(z) >0$ show that for every $z\in D$ $\quad$$f(z)$ is one to one function.

I was thinking on using the cauchy reiman eqations \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\-\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\end{bmatrix}

Now this matrix is reversible since $Ref'(z) >0$ and the determinant is not zero. now I wanted to show in some way that $f(z_1) = f(z_2) \rightarrow  z_1 = z_2$ I am trying to think how should I use the fact that $D$ is convex set can help me here.

Also, why this is not the case anymore when $D$ is startlike domain? namely , there exist $z_0 \in D$ such that for every $z \in D$ and $t \in (0,1)$ $$tz_1 +(1-t)z_2 \in D$$

Comment: I have added another reference to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4099426/42969

Comment: Btw, it is "Riemann", not "Reiman".

Comment: And a counterexample for non-convex domains is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3354444/42969

Comment: @MartinR I am not sure I understood his counter example. I have been told a hint to observe the function $f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$. do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a,b\in\mathbb D$, $a\ne b$ and $f(a)=f(b)$. Then
$$
0=f(b)-f(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f\big(a+t(b-a)\big)\,dt
=\int_0^1 f'\big(a+t(b-a)\big)\cdot(b-a)\,dt \\
=(b-a)\int_0^1 f'\big(a+t(b-a)\big)\,dt
$$
and thus
$$
\int_0^1 f'\big(a+t(b-a)\big)\,dt=0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\int_0^1 {\mathrm{Re}}\,f'\big(a+t(b-a)\big)\,dt=0.
$$
Contradiction.